# generate dynamic main menu text boxes in hierarchy with sub menu text boxes along with add(+) n remove(-) functionality on button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{CreateTextBoxes();
 CreateSubMenuBoxes();
}
```

[create text box func](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC3yy.png)

[add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkrNe.png)

Comment: no its part of my form which i have to built

Comment: can you show what you tried, and where specifically you are stuck?

Comment: // i have add my function for text boxes as image

Comment: paste code part in question, don't add images of it

Comment: // actually i got stuck in creating connection between main menu with sub menu . i ws trying to add but there was indentation problem i tried to reslove it but it is not accepting my code